# SQL How to pull data only from 1st of the month backwards

Tags: sql, database, date

I am not a great SQL programmer.  I want to do this:

```
Select incidentnumber
from Incident
where createddate >45
```

this works fine.  I want to be able to run this anytime during a month but only get data up to the 1st of that month (monthly report)

So June 12th I run the report for the meeting. I only want items that are greater then 45 days as of June 1.  How do I tell it that?

I've tried datediff, Date_Trunc with Current_Date and Interval, and other date functions but none do what I want it to do. At least I can't make it do what I want.

Comment: tag with database.

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: Possibly something like `createddate < date_sub(current_date, interval day(current_date) + 45 days)` It's not clear whether time components come into play or how the boundary should work but that's a start.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say very much -- about what platform you are using or what your data model is.  Assuming the datefield column has the date you want to compare against and you are using SQL Server (which has the function NOW() for the current timestamp, this will work.

```
SELECT -- something
FROM -- sometable
WHERE (MONTH(datefield) < MONTH(NOW()) AND YEAR(datefield) = YEAR(NOW()) 
      OR YEAR(datefield) < YEAR(NOW())
```

How does this work? for items in the current year it checks that month is before the current month.  For items before the current year it just includes them.